# scrollViewDidScroll not executing

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiscrollview

I think have decent experience working with iPhone development.
as much I know.. I did set up the delegate.. 
I have from top to botton
UIView --> UIScrollView--> UITextView

I tried everything... to get the event scrollView to fire the scrollViewDidScroll event.

is anything wrong with the structure.. 
there not much of the code to post here.
what I am trying to do is.. do something when UITextView is scrolled.

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder or are you setting everything up in code?

Comment: as I said there is nothing much code.. I am setting everything in interface builder... what I want is do some stuff when UITextView get scrolled..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry did not respond... Just wanted to share in case anyone need this...
I used delegate methods of parent i.e. UIView for UIScrollView i.e. Child it worked..

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without some code or a screenshot.  Is the scroll view actually scrolling? If you set it up in Interface Builder, did you change the size of the scroll view's contentSize in code so that it can actually scroll?  Maybe the text view is eating the scroll events; did you try setting the text view's delegate to see if it's firing a scrollViewDidScroll event?